# Changing the displayed IP in mstsc's connection bar

Tags: remote-desktop

I have an application which allows me to connect to 127.x.x.x and automatically be redirected to a remote machine.
When I use mstsc to connect to this address, the title is the ip - 127.x.x.x.
Is there a way for me to change the title (when in full screen mode = connection bar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the name you want displayed to your `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file and use that name to use in the "Connect to" field in the RDP client. Your `hosts` file would look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain remoteHostname-rdp
```

Add the '-rdp' or some other suffix to avoid collisions with the real name in the host.

Comment: brilliant! exactly what I needed!